# VisualBasic: casting Exception into ErrObject

Tags: vb.net, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I am about to refactor some old VisualBasic application and have come along with the following situation:

```
Public Sub MySub ()
     Try
        ' execute dangerous operation
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Call HandleErrors((ErrObject) ex)  ' <-- invalide cast
    End Try
End SuB

Public Sub HandleErrors(ByRef objError As ErrObject)   ' I can not easily change the signature of this sub as it gets referenced very often.
    ' process error ..
End Sub
```

I would like to reuse the already existing Sub  ‘HandleErrors()’, which takes an ErrObject as parameter.  But since I am more comfortable to use Try and Catch, I would like to pass an Object of the type Syste.Exception, rather than an ErrObject.

**Question**:

Is there any way of casting or transforming the Exception into an ErrObject ?

Comment: Why not start the refactoring with an overload of `HandleErrors` that can deal with the modern `Exception`, rather than trying to force all the new code through the old stuff, which you'll end up having to change again as and when you refactor out the original `HandleErrors` anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to force exceptions into the historic Visual Basic error handling routines, I think the better option here is to create a new overload of `HandleErrors` (leaving the original sub signature untouched for the places that still use it), possibly with an entirely new function that both the original function and new overload can then call.  For instance, lets's assume your function currently looks like this:

```
Public Sub HandleErrors(ByRef objError As ErrObject)
    Log(objError.Description)
    PerformSomeGlobalCleanup()
End Sub
```

And now you want to also be able to log the new-style exceptions too.  You could just create a new overload:

```
Public Sub HandleErrors(ByRef ex As Exception)
    Log(ex.Message)
    PerformSomeGlobalCleanup()
End Sub
```

But it would be better for this code to share the underlying structure and logic of whatever `HandleErrors` is actually doing, so you could do this for instance:

```
Private Sub InternalHandleErrors(ByVal msg as String)
    Log(msg)
    PerformSomeGlobalCleanup()
End Sub

Public Sub HandleErrors(ByRef ex As Exception)
    InternalHandleErrors(ex.Message)
End Sub

Public Sub HandleErrors(ByRef objError As ErrObject)
    'original signature, but refactored
    InternalHandleErrors(objError.Description)
End Sub
```

You can move as much logic from the original `HandleErrors` into `InternalHandleErrors` as makes sense - whatever is common between handling an `ErrObject` and an `Exception`.

This means you're not "polluting" the newly refactored code with old-style Visual Basic objects, and means that if/when you complete the refactoring to remove the original function when nothing else references it, you don't need to go through your entire code base removing the casts.

Comment: Just as an aside, `ByRef` is not needed here since you are not changing the reference to the object.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Indeed - that's a manifestation of the OPs code pervading into my example :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,since it seems there is no easy way to do this, I decided to overload the HandleError Sub and introduce a new class to generalise the Exceptions.

```
Public Sub MySub ()
     Try
        ' execute dangerous operation
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Call HandleErrors((ErrObject) ex)  ' <-- invalide cast
    End Try
End SuB


Class GeneralError
    Public ReadOnly Number As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Source As String
    Public ReadOnly Description As String

    Sub New(exception As System.Exception)
        Number = 1
        Source = exception.Source
        Description = exception.Message
    End Sub

    Sub New(errObject As ErrObject)
        Number = errObject.Number
        Source = errObject.Source
        Description = errObject.Description
    End Sub
End Class

Public Sub HandleErrors(ByRef errObject As ErrObject)   ' Overload
    Dim generalError As GeneralError = New GeneralError(errObject )
    Call HandleErrors(generalError)
End Sub

Public Sub HandleErrors(ByRef exception As Exception)   ' Overload
    Dim generalError As GeneralError = New GeneralError(exception)
    Call HandleErrors(generalError)
End Sub


Private Sub HandleErrors(ByRef generalError As GeneralError)   ' Original
    ' process error ..
End Sub
```

Comment: Just as an aside, `ByRef` is not needed here since you are not changing the reference to the object.